# Citation problem with multiple sources

Tags: citing

I have imported the cite and the natbib packages. If I use \cite{author A}, it works. If I use \cite{author B}, it still works. But if I both have those citations at the same time, it doesn't work anymore. I am really confused since using only one citation works but using multiple in a text doesn't work. I am sure that my bibliography, keys etc. are well defined.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You should take a look at `biblatex`, which defines some ‘multicite’ commands.

Answer (score 0):

I did not load the `cite` package and it works just fine with `natbib`. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}

\begin{document}

some text \cite{latexcompanion,knuthwebsite,einstein}. 

\medskip

\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

The file `sample.bib`:

```
@article{einstein,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
        [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}

@book{latexcompanion,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The \LaTeX\ Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}

@misc{knuthwebsite,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html"
}
```

The output:

[image]

The [Overleaf documentation](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_with_natbib#The_bibliography_file) has a very good explanation on the use of natbib, biblatex and bibtex.